# CMake: Getting the library output directory of a library target

Tags: cmake

I found a lot of information on how to set a custom library output directory via setting the targets `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property for single config generators and `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>` for multi config generators.

I want to do the opposite: Querying the output directory of a target created via
`add_library (lib_name SHARED)`

A simple straightforward `get_target_property(LIB_OUTPUT_DIR lib_name LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)` always sets `LIB_OUTPUT_DIR` to `LIB_OUTPUT_DIR-NOTFOUND` and I can't figure out what's wrong with this. I'm using the makefile generator on macOS, as automatically set up by  VSCode. But I want my solution to work on all kind of single- & multi config generators. What's the right way to achieve that?

Comment: `What's the right way to achieve that?` generator expressions. Because, as name suggests, they work on generator side.

Comment: I see, but I'm failing to create a proper expression for the property to query. My approach was `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:_DEBUG>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:_RELEASE>` which I hope to evaluate to `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` for a debug config and to `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE` for a release config, but it still leads to the same error. What's a proper expression here?

Comment: Generator expression work when building, not on configuration stage. It would be `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:lib_name>`

Comment: There could be an easier way of achieving what you're trying tho do provided the place where you want to use the value supports generator expressions. (It's not as simple as "mutli config generators use `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`": a generator expression for `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` can be achieved to produce similar effects without setting the output dir per configuration.)

Comment: @PluginPenguin Did you find a way to do this?